# Can't track unique visitors with cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, analytics, ab-testing

I am debugging a split testing app. It tracks visits, unique visitors, presents a variable, and tracks conversions. It's implementation by loading a JavaScript file onto the page being tested.

When the JavaScript (and supporting files) are on the same domain as the page being tested it works perfectly... but when they are on different domains, one aspect fails: It still tracks visitors, shows a variable, and tracks conversions, **but no longer tracks *unique* visitors.**

Tracking is done via cookie.

**tracker.js.php** this is the file linked on the page being tracked

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function log(log){
    console.log(log);
}

<?php
// SETTINGS
include_once 'settings.php'; 
header('Content-type:text/javascript'); 
?>

// VISITOR COOKIE
var cookie_match_id =       '<?php echo $settings['cookie_id']; ?>',
    cookie_id       =       String(getCookie('id')),
    price_index     =       getCookie('index'),
    prices          =       [<?php echo implode(',', $settings['price']); ?>],
    prices_amount   =       prices.length;

// IF PRICE IS EMPTY, OR COOKIE DOESN'T MATCH, SET IT
if(!price_index.length || cookie_id!=cookie_match_id){
    price_index = ~~(Math.random() * prices_amount);
    setCookie('index', price_index, 365);
    setCookie('id', cookie_match_id, 365);
}

// STORE
var price = prices[price_index];
$('#random1').html('$'+price); 

// TRACK
$.get('http://mywebsite.com/track.php', {track:true, variation:price_index}); // track visit

$('#target1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('http://mywebsite.com/track.php', {track:true, conversion:true, variation:price_index}); // track conversion
    return false;
});
```

**settings.php** is used to edit the variables (price)

```
<?php
extract($_POST);

$disabled_text = 'disabled';
$settings_file = 'settings.json';
$visitor_log_file = 'visitor_log.json'; 
$settings = json_decode(file_get_contents($settings_file), true);

if(isset($edit)){
    $disabled_text = '';
} else if(isset($submit)){
    $settings['variable_id'] = $variable_id;
    $settings['target_id'] = $target_id;
    $settings['price'] = $price;
    $settings['cookie_id'] = rand();
    $settings_json = json_encode($settings);
    file_put_contents($settings_file, $settings_json);
    $visitor_log = array();
    $x = 0;
    foreach($price as $each){
        $visitor_log[$x]["price"] = $each;
        $visitor_log[$x]["visitors"] = '0';
        $visitor_log[$x]["unique_visitors"] = '0';
        $visitor_log[$x]["conversions"] = '0';
        $x++;
    }
    $visitor_log_json = json_encode($visitor_log);
    file_put_contents($visitor_log_file, $visitor_log_json);
}

extract($settings);
?>
```

**track.php** the file that actually does the tracking

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client-site.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

//CONFIG    
include_once 'settings.php';
$prices = $settings['price'];
session_start();

//VARIABLES
extract($_REQUEST);
$visitor_log = 'visitor_log.json';
$visitor_log_contents = file_get_contents($visitor_log);
$visitor_log_contents = json_decode($visitor_log_contents, false);

//SAVE SERVER COOKIE
if(!isset($_SESSION['cookie_id']) || $_SESSION['cookie_id']!=$settings['cookie_id']){
    $_SESSION['cookie_id'] = $settings['cookie_id'];

    unset($_SESSION['visited']);
    unset($_SESSION['converted']);
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['visited'])){
    $_SESSION['visited'] = true;
    $log_visitor = true;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['converted']) && isset($conversion)){
    $_SESSION['converted'] = true;
    $log_conversion = true;
}

//LOG

$price_index = $variation;
$price = $prices[$price_index];
$l = $visitor_log_contents[$price_index];
if(!isset($l->visitors))$l->visitors = 0;
$l->visitors++; //total visits
if(isset($log_visitor))$l->unique_visitors++; 
if(isset($log_conversion))$l->conversions++; 

$visitor_log_contents[$price_index] = $l;

// STORE
$visitor_log_contents = json_encode($visitor_log_contents);
file_put_contents($visitor_log, $visitor_log_contents);

?>
```

NOTE: It seems to be that the cookie is sticking, because part of its' job is to ensure that once a price is shown to a person, they only see that same price every new pageload, which works. But for some reason, they are not logged as a returning visitor, and are counted as new with each page load.

I've tried adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client-site.com");` which reduced some errors, but didn't fix the problem. Also have tried `session_unset` instead of `unset` in `track.php` with no luck. Lots of other trial and error which has not worked. Can someone help?

*NOTE: don't be fooled by my reputation - I'm a total hack - I got it all from a few good answers about Bootstrap.*

Comment: Might need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` to your headers as well

Comment: seems to make no difference, sadly

Comment: This _is_ most likely a cookie problem. You say it is “sticking”, because you can see cookie-dependent output on the page - but my guess would be that the cookie is not _kept_ after the browsing session, due to browser settings. Since your script is on a different domain, its cookies become “3rd party” cookies, and these are usually treated differently. (A P3P policy can increase the amount of clients that accept such 3rd party cookies.)

Comment: I've inspected my cookies in settings and they do stick around. Have also restarted the browser and sure enough, there they are...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one domain and a few sub-domains or are all the domains different?

If you're using sub-domains you will have to specify your main domain in the `setCookie` function:

```
setcookie('name', 'value' , 0 , "" , 'domain.com');
```

http://php.net/set_cookie

Comment: they are all at different domains